# How do I achieve this style of line that is smooth and consistent with corners?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, illustration, drawing, line-art

I would like to know an efficient way to achieve this style of line that is consistent and smooth, especially around the **corners and angles**? Thank you so much.

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome. Unfortunately this is not a tutorial on demand site, although it sometimes seems that way. You need to preferably be more specific and show us either what you have tried (so that we can estimate what your problem is) or explain what your exact problem is. There is already one close vote on your post (not by me), so please **[edit your question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/104564/edit)**. I mean surely you know that you can expand strokes and round corners? Also because your just tagging everything its even hard to know whet you want to be using.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you already know the basics of using the Pen tool. Anyway, here's how I would reproduce such a graphic using Illustrator.  I don't know if I would describe it as "efficient". To achieve the effect requires some manual work, which is unsurprising as the artwork looks hand drawn rather than the perfection you usually get using a vector image editor.

- Draw the basic shape, and apply a tapered stroke brush. See the
  middle example in blue below. The stroke I chose is highlighted in red in the brushes panel.
- Use the Width tool to vary the thickness of the line
- Expand the artwork, then Simplify the path - I used about 75% for the
  Curve Precision. Sometimes simplifying produces unwanted anchors. You may have to delete these or fix them manually.
- Use Live Corners to round the corners as required. And make any adjustments to
  the finished path. The finished example is on the right below in red.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Greatly appreciate your breakdown of the process. Really wanted to see how someone with more experience would approach simple line work. I am VERY new at this. Bullet point 3 was particularly helpful!